# Nomina sacra in ancient manuscripts

Tags: manuscript, nomina-sacra

The oldest manuscripts we have show the nomina sacra for Jesus and the Father.  Which are the oldest manuscripts that have the name "Iesous"  "Theos" etc fully spelled out instead of abbreviating them with a line over them?

Comment: Sorry I don’t have time to answe. See http://www.tyndalehouse.com/TynBul/Library/TynBull_2003_54_1_01_Hurtado_P52Rylands.pdf